# How to list all R Markdown templates in a package?

Tags: r, r-markdown

### General Problem

Given a package that provides R Markdown templates, **how does one get a list of all valid templates** that could be given to the `rmarkdown::draft` function? That is, for

```r
rmarkdown::draft("my_rmd.Rmd", template_name, some_pkg)
```

where we know `some_pkg`, how can one programmatically obtain the valid values for `template_name`?

### Example Package: reprex

As a concrete example of a template provider, let's use the **reprex** package. From the RStudio GUI, I know **reprex** provides two templates. How can one get the list of `template_names` for the **reprex** package?

### What I've Looked Through

Skimming through the `rmarkdown::` methods, I don't see any such functionality. Searching around, I've only found examples for how to write and use templates, but all eventually resort to showing how to load the template via the RStudio GUI dialog. The documentation of the `rmarkdown::draft` only describes where the templates are stored, but doesn't provide a programmatic example for listing them.

Comment: There is an internal function for listing all template directories which takes the same approach as your solution below.  `rmarkdown:::list_template_dirs()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `available_templates()`

Starting with `rmarkdown` v2.12, there is now an exported function for this. For example,

```r
rmarkdown::available_templates("reprex")
```

See [v2.12 Release Notes](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/releases/tag/v2.12).

Answer (score 2):

### Directory Listing

One solution is to search the package's installation directory for templates. For the **reprex** case, we have

```r
## get package root directory
pkg_dir <- system.file(package="reprex")

## list all directory names corresponding to templates
list.dirs(paste0(pkg_dir, "/rmarkdown/templates"), recursive=FALSE, full.names=FALSE)
## [1] "reprex-featureful" "reprex-minimal" 

## verify they work
rmarkdown::draft("test", "reprex-minimal", "reprex")
```

While this works, I find it rather unsatisfactory and would expect there to be a dedicated function for this. But perhaps I overestimate the demand for programmatically working with templates.